# Timer rodar determinada hora

Tags: delphi

Preciso fazer um timer que rode todos os dias as 18 horas e pressione um Button. Não achei nada na internet a respeito disso, alguma sugestão ?

Tentei o seguinte, mais ele não faz nada:

> // TIMER INTERVAL: 60000

```delphi
var
  hora: TDateTime;
begin
hora := now;
  if hora = strtotime('18:00:00') then
  begin
    Button2.Click;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Tiago, isso mesmo, sera um FORM com um TIMER que todos os dias as 18:00hrs ele deve apenas clicar em um botão Button2.click, apenas isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para isso você precisa de algo que faça a verificação de tempos em tempos.
Uma rotina única que não se repete não irá servir.

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é usar o componente ***Timer*** do *Delphi*.
Ele se encontra na aba *System* da paleta de componentes.

Aqui:

[image: TTimer - classic layout]

Ou aqui, dependendo da versão do delphi e do layout que está utilizando:

[image: TTImer - classic layout]

Então basta adicionar esse componente ao seu *Form* e certificar-se que a propriedade ***Enable*** está ***True***.

**Se você necessita de precisão na hora da execução, então seu intervalo (propriedade *Interval*) deve ser igual a 1000.**

Feito isso, basta dar dois cliques no componente ***Timer*** para que seja criado seu método principal, que é do evento ***OnTimer***.

Então você precisa escrever a rotina desse método:

```delphi
procedure TMeuForm.timerTarefaTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Time = StrToTime('18:00:00') then
    btnTarefa.Click;
    // ou btnTarefaClick(nil);
end;
```

Dessa forma, com 1000 milisegundos setados no *Inverval* do componente *Timer*, você terá o processo sendo executado exatamente às 18hrs como informado no código.

---

## Se você não necessita de precisão no horário de execução e deseja apenas ter uma tarefa sendo executada próximo à esse horário, então pode economizar em ciclos de verificação do *Timer* da seguinte maneira:

Já que você pretende informar um invervalo igual a 60000 (60 mil milisegundos = 60 min. = 1 hora) você pode fazer dessa forma:

Adicione em seu *Form* uma variável que armazenará a data e hora do último dia que a tarefa foi executada.

```delphi
private
  FUltimaExecucao: TDate;
end;
```

Ela pode ser iniciada com zero.

```delphi
procedure TMeuForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FUltimaExecucao := 0;
end;
```

E então efetuar sua verificação da seguinte forma:

```delphi
procedure TMeuForm.timerTarefaTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Time >= StrToTime('18:00:00')) and (Time <= StrToTime('19:00:00')) and 
    (FUltimaExecucao < Date)then
  begin
    btnTarefa.Click;
    // ou btnTarefaClick(nil);
    FUltimaExecucao = Date;
  end;
end;
```

Assim, você não terá precisão do horário que foi executado, mas terá menos ciclos de execução do componente ***Timer***.